# pxlib - howto query with where-clause?

Tags: php, paradox

I'm using pxlib through php to query get some data in an ancient paradox-db.

I don't understand how I'm supposed to get a limited recordset from the db,
docs at https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.paradox.php

I'm thinking of some kind of where-clause...

Anyone with paradox knowledge, please fill the gothic gap, ;-)

Comment: ok, pxlib seems to be hardcore. Any recommended odbc driver for paradox version 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

pxlib doesn't have any kind of sql-interface and can't use indexes to find records.

looping through the fysical table is the only way.

working pxlib.dll was found in xampp 1.7.1 (oldie)